# ServiceBusTrigger with enqueueTimeUtc argument fails when triggered via HTTP endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm developing a Service Bus Trigger in Azure Functions v1 locally with Visual Studio 2017. I want to test the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#trigger---c-example) from the official docs without having to put a message in the service bus. So I trigger it via Postman at endpoint POST http://localhost:7071/admin/functions/ServiceBusQueueTriggerCSharp with body `{ "input": "foo" }`.

This fails with a script host error: **Exception while executing function: ServiceBusQueueTriggerCSharp. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: One or more errors occurred. Exception binding parameter 'deliveryCount'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Binding data does not contain expected value 'deliveryCount'.**

I tried removing the `deliveryCount` argument, but then it fails at `enqueueTimeUtc`. Removing that too works. Is there a way to keep these arguments and test the Function locally?

I understand that these two arguments wouldn't make much sense when triggered via HTTP, but they could be given default values. `messageId` has a non-zero value.

Example for reference:

```
[FunctionName("ServiceBusQueueTriggerCSharp")]                    
public static void Run(
    [ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue", AccessRights.Manage, Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")] 
    string myQueueItem,
    Int32 deliveryCount,       // this fails
    DateTime enqueuedTimeUtc,  // this fails too
    string messageId,
    TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {myQueueItem}");
    log.Info($"EnqueuedTimeUtc={enqueuedTimeUtc}");
    log.Info($"DeliveryCount={deliveryCount}");
    log.Info($"MessageId={messageId}");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of right now, if you want to be able to work with these additional metadata properties, you'll need to use a real service bus message.

In theory, the admin endpoint could be smart enough to allow you to pass additional binding data (such as deliveryCount in this case) as query parameters. I filed the following feature request to track:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2955

Comment: Thanks for opening the feature request, Paul.